# I can not lock screen in 13.10

Tags: 13.10

After upgrade to 13.10 from 13.04 I can not lock screen.

When i try to lock screen from the panel, nothing happen.

Thanks.-

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already solved this issue. I noticed the same problem today. This is how I fixed it:

1. Open Unity Tweak Tool. If you have not installed it yet, I would recommend to do it.
2. Click on Security settings, under System
3. Make sure that under "Enhance system security by disabling:" is all unchecked. Specially the option for "Desktop lock"

Answer (score -1):

In system settings > Brightness & Lock check that `Lock` is on.

Also make sure that the `gnome-screensaver` package is installed

Comment: That does not help in any way in my case - I have lock set to "On", package is the newest available, but there is no lock option.

Comment: Well then start your own question describing what session your on, what release of Ubuntu,  ect. In any normal not screwed with install of Ubuntu there such a panel with a lock option.

Comment: That was clean install of Ubuntu 13.10, switched to Gnome (not Unity) at login screen. I have added Gnome Shell extension to actually display lock button at the top, and have keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+L) to cause it too. No custom configuration, just what I described (all through UI), so I would not call it "not normal" or "screwed" installation.